# DevExpress ASPxPopupMenu: Dynamic Menu Items

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

How do I make the menu items displayed in an ASPxPopupMenu dynamic based on the node right-clicked in an ASPxTreeList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASPxPopupMenu is a server side control and thus its content can only be changed in the server code.  So, it is impossible to add / remove items using client code only.  However, there is a workaround.  You can add all possible items to the menu at design time and manage their visibility in client code.  For example, this can be done within the menu's client side PopUp event handler:

```
menu.GetItemByName("someItemName").SetVisible(false);
```

Here you will find client side documentation for the ASPxPopupMenu:

[ASPxClientPopupMenu Members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxMenuScriptsASPxClientPopupMenuMembersTopicAll)

Comment: Thanks!  I set the menu item's visibility in the client side ContextMenu event handler per your recommendation. It works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Please also take a look at the http://www.devexpress.com/example=E145 Code Central example, which may be helpful in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code sample.  This was very helpful.